# Collision Detection not working in cocos2dx v3 using Physics

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I want to collide 2 sprites using Physics Engine.
But my contact listener is not responding. and no warning/error on log or runtime.
So here is what i did :

Declaration

```
1)cocos2d::PhysicsWorld* m_world;
2)void setPhyWorld(cocos2d::PhysicsWorld* world){m_world = world;}
3)bool onContactBegin(cocos2d::PhysicsContact& contact);
```

Implementation
For PhysicsWorld:
Scene ->

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics();
    scene->getPhysicsWorld()->setDebugDrawMask(PhysicsWorld::DEBUGDRAW_ALL);

    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    layer->setPhyWorld(scene->getPhysicsWorld());

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

PhysicsWorld->

```
void HelloWorld::createPhysicsWorld(){

    auto body = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(visibleSize, PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT, 3);
    auto edgeNode = Node::create();
    edgeNode->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2));
    edgeNode->setPhysicsBody(body);
    this->addChild(edgeNode);
}
```

Creating Sprite->

```
void HelloWorld::createCar(){
    car = Sprite::create("car.png");

    auto body3 = PhysicsBody::createBox(car->getContentSize());
    body3->setDynamic(false);
    body3->setCategoryBitmask(2);
    body3->setCollisionBitmask(2);
    body3->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    car->setPhysicsBody(body3);
    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    car->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(car, 1);

    car->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0.5, 0));

    car->setFlippedX(true);
}

void HelloWorld::createRocket(){
    rocket = Sprite::create("rocket.png");

    auto body2 = PhysicsBody::createBox(rocket->getContentSize());
    body2->setDynamic(false);
    body2->setCategoryBitmask(1);
    body2->setCollisionBitmask(1);
    body2->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    rocket->setPhysicsBody(body2);

    // position the sprite on the center of the screen
    rocket->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x,origin.y));

    // add the sprite as a child to this layer
    this->addChild(rocket, 1);

}
```

Collision->

```
 auto contactListener = EventListenerPhysicsContact::create();
    contactListener->onContactBegin = CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::onContactBegin, this);
    this->getEventDispatcher()->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(contactListener,this);
```

ContactListner->

```
bool HelloWorld::onContactBegin(cocos2d::PhysicsContact& contact)
{   
    CCLOG("onContactBegin -------> ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think that collision bitmask has to be the same. From the cocos Reference: _This body’s collision mask is compared to the other body’s category mask by performing a logical AND operation_

Comment: I did that as well. but setCollisionBitmask is use to detect which physics body has collide with other physics body to perform different action.

Comment: This looks a whole lot more like Box2D than Chipmunk, changed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Just Comment out  `body2->setDynamic(false);` inside createRocket Method and setGravityEnable(false); and it works now.

```
void HelloWorld::createRocket(){
    rocket = Sprite::create("rocket.png");
    rocket->setPosition(Vec2(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x,origin.y - 50));
    rocket->setTag(3);
    auto body2 = PhysicsBody::createBox(rocket->getContentSize());
    //body2->setDynamic(false);
    body2->setTag(3);
    body2->setGravityEnable(false);
    body2->setCollisionBitmask(3);
    body2->setContactTestBitmask(true);
    rocket->setPhysicsBody(body2);

    this->addChild(rocket, 1);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it is tricky thing that you miss in your code.one body should be setDynamic to true.

body->setDynamic(true);

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turned out that it was bit ugly mistake.

```
body3->setContactTestBitmask(true);
```

this method's argument is a bitmask not 'true'/'false' field, so your 'true' mask was treated as it was 1 while your bodies mask is 2. The solution is:

```
body3->setCategoryBitmask(1);
body3->setCollisionBitmask(3);
body3->setContactTestBitmask(1);

body2->setCategoryBitmask(3);
body2->setCollisionBitmask(1);
body2->setContactTestBitmask(1);
```

Comment: it's better to use hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: How can I thank you? I wasted hours setting the wrong "contact test mask". I read the API reference and found that the contact won't be registered until the contact test mask and the category mask's logical AND is a non-zero value.